# merging two data frames on two different columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge between two dataframes but based on a condition so the output will be the merged dataframe on 2 different columns based on that condition when I try to use the if condition like this

```py
if RSRP_cal['new'] > 90 or RSRP_cal['new'] < -90 :
    RSRP_new = pd.merge(RSRP_cal , tilt ,left_on = 'int_theta',  right_on='mapped_neg_tilt_angle' ,how = 'left')
else:
    RSRP_new = pd.merge(RSRP_cal , tilt ,left_on = 'int_theta',  right_on='mapped_tilt_angle' ,how = 'left')
```

this error occurs:

```py
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: You are trying to compare whole Series (all "cells" in column new) with a single value and that's the reason for the error. If your condition says that *any* or *all* values in Series must be between -90 and 90 to merge Dataframes with int_theta and mapped_neg_tilt_angle IDs, then use **RSRP_cal['new'].any() > 90 or RSRP_cal['new'].any() < -90** (or all if each value must be within the limit). If you want to merge only rows meeting the condition, use mask instead (like in the anser from Grzegorz)

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a little unclear. Adding some more details will definitely help. But for now, with the details you mentioned, you are trying to merge RSRP_cal with tilt.
The usage of the function `merge` according to you was `pd.merge` but the right format is,

```
temp = RSRP_cal.merge(tilt ,left_on = 'int_theta', right_on='mapped_neg_tilt_angle' ,how = 'left'))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I need to merge RSRP_cal with tilt but based on a condition if the values in column (new) in RSRP is >90 or < -90 then merge based on  column (mapped_neg_tilt_angle) in tilt otherwise merge on (mapped_tilt_angle) column in tilt

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if the merge parameters are correct, if there are true values on each occasion (>90 or <-90) you should probably change the name of the variable of the 2nd "RSRP_new", because this would be ambiguous. If this doesn't work, then you should consider a "for" loop which would iterate for every row of the dataframe. What is the shape of RSRP_cal?

Comment: The merge parameters are correct but my problem is that I am trying to find 2 output merges based on that condition if the values in column (new) in RSRP is >90 or < -90 then I want to merge the 2 dataframes on the mapped_neg_tilt_angle column otherwise I want the merge to be on the mapped_tilt_angle column.

RSRP_cal is a dataframe containing 7 columns there are two columns I want to merge based on them

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
mask = RSRP_cal['new'].abs().gt(90)

RSRP_new = pd.merge(RSRP_cal.loc[mask] , tilt , /
    left_on = 'int_theta',  right_on='mapped_neg_tilt_angle' , /
    how = 'left')

RSRP_new = pd.concat([RSRP_new, /
    pd.merge(RSRP_cal.loc[~mask], tilt, /
    left_on = 'int_theta',  right_on='mapped_tilt_angle', /
    how = 'left')])
```